# Not able to Stick the element using Sticky Kit inside Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

My aim is to stick element inside the modal, sticky kit work like charm for non modal screens.

I tired put id/ class to the parent element but nothing seems to be working.

I am not able to figure out what exactly needs to be done

```
$(".sidebar").stick_in_parent({
 offset_top: 10,
 parent: ".modal-body"
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kunalvashist/j5t2mcLh/) for the same

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this code here:**

this issue solves easily use to position sticky but position sticky not support oldest browsers.

you change the following code here:

```
.modal-content {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  overflow: auto;
  }
  .modal-content .modal-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #fff;
  }
  .modal-alternate-wrapper {
    position: sticky;
    top: 60px;
  }
```

I update only this above code:

```js
$('#myModalHorizontal').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){
 console.log("init sticky");
 $(".sidebar").stick_in_parent({
    offset_top: 10,
    parent: ".modal-body"
 });
})
```

```css
.modal-body .form-horizontal .col-sm-2,
.modal-body .form-horizontal .col-sm-10 {
    width: 100%
}

.modal-body .form-horizontal .control-label {
    text-align: left;
}

.modal-body .form-horizontal .col-sm-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

* {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.modal-content {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow: auto;
}

.modal-content .modal-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #fff;
}

.modal-alternate-wrapper {
    position: sticky;
    top: 60px;
}

.wrapper,
.header,
.main,
.footer {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 10px;
}

.header {
    background-color: #6289AE;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 100px;
}

.sidebar {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.main {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 600px;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #6289AE;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 250px;
}

.top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}

.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalHorizontal">
    Launch Horizontal Form
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalHorizontal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    Modal title
                </h4>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="header"> <a class="top">header top</a>
                    <a class="bottom">header bottom</a>

                </div>
                <div class="container modal-alternate-wrapper">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <div class="sidebar">
                                <a class="top">sidebar top</a>
                                <a class="bottom">sidebar bottom</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <div class="main"> <a class="top">main top</a>
                                <a class="bottom">main bottom</a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer"> <a class="top">footer top</a>
                    <a class="bottom">footer bottom</a>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save changes
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### **Thank you**